edit a image saved in core data
in my code which is all listed below in the first class the user drags rectangles around and can save how it looks. The middle class is a library where you can see all of the saved artwork. In the last class you see the full screen pic of the saved image. What I would like to do is in the middle class edit the saved image so you can rearranged the boxes. I don't know if this is something you have to create a file to do. Think of this as several different photoshop files that I would like to edit and save their design.

import UIKit;import CoreData


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var rectangleB = UIButton()

    var arrTextFields = [UIImageView]()
    

    var libaryB = UIButton()
    
    

    
    var ww = 80
    var currentView: UIView?
    var saveB = UIButton()
    
    var clearB = UIButton()
    var txt = UITextField()
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white
       
        
        [rectangleB, saveB, libaryB, clearB,txt].forEach {
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor(
                red: .random(in: 0.5...0.7),
                green: .random(in: 0.0...1),
                blue: .random(in: 0.3...0.5),
                alpha: 1
            )
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            
            

            if let textfield = $0 as? UITextField {
                textfield.textAlignment = .center
                textfield.inputAccessoryView = createToolbar()
            }

            if let label = $0 as? UILabel {
                label.textAlignment = .center
            }
            if let button = $0 as? UIButton {
                button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            }
        }
     
        
        
        libaryB.setTitle("Library", for: .normal)
        saveB.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
        libaryB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(libraryBtn), for: .touchDown)
        // note that I changed some of the constraints to use the safeAreaLayoutGuide of the view
        // you wouldn't want your sliders to go out of the safe area, would you?
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            
            
            txt.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            txt.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            txt.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.05),
            txt.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/4),
            
            
            
            
            
            rectangleB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            rectangleB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            rectangleB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.05),
            rectangleB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/4),
            
          
            
            saveB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            saveB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectangleB.trailingAnchor),
            saveB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.05),
            saveB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/4),
            
            libaryB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            libaryB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: saveB.trailingAnchor),
            libaryB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.05),
            libaryB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/4),

            
          
            
            clearB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectangleB.topAnchor),
            clearB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.05),
            clearB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/3),
            clearB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),

         
        ])
        
        rectangleB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rectangleBox), for: .touchDown)
        
     
        rectangleB.setTitle("Rectangle", for: .normal)
        
        
     
        clearB.setTitle("Clear", for: .normal)
        
        clearB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearM), for: .touchDown)
        saveB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saveM), for: .touchDown)
    }
    
    
    
    @objc func saveM() {
        
        if let textEntered = self.txt.text {
            if textEntered.isEmpty != true {
                saver()
                print("Saves the textfield text")
                
            } else { saver()}
        }
        
        
        txt.resignFirstResponder()
        txt.text = ""
        clearM()
        
    }
    
    
    @objc func clearM() {
        // Loop through all the subviews in arrTextFields and remove them from the superview
        for subview in arrTextFields {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
        // Clear the array since all views have been removed
        arrTextFields.removeAll()
        
        // Optionally, clear the currentView reference as well
        currentView = nil
    }

    @objc func rectangleBox() {
        let subview = UIImageView()
        
        subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        arrTextFields.append(subview)
        view.addSubview(subview)
        
        subview.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY + CGFloat(ww), width: CGFloat(ww), height: 35)
        subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        
        // Add a border to the subview
        subview.layer.borderWidth = 2.0  // Set the border width
        subview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor  // Set the border color
        
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGestured(_:)))
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGestured(_:)))
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


        

        // Automatically select the new rectangle
        currentView = subview
    }

    

    
    
    
    @objc func sxBTN(sender: UISlider) {
        guard let currentView = currentView else { return }

        let newWidth = CGFloat(ww) * CGFloat(sender.value)
      //  let fixedHeight = CGFloat(35) // Keep the height fixed
        
        
        let currentHeight = currentView.bounds.height  // Use the already set width, keep it fixed
        
        
        

        currentView.bounds.size = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: currentHeight)

        // Bottom label for width measurement
        let bottomLabel: UILabel
        if currentView.subviews.count > 0, let label = currentView.subviews[0] as? UILabel {
            bottomLabel = label
        } else {
            bottomLabel = UILabel()
            currentView.addSubview(bottomLabel)
        }

        // Left label for height measurement
        let leftLabel: UILabel
        if currentView.subviews.count > 1, let label = currentView.subviews[1] as? UILabel {
            leftLabel = label
        } else {
            leftLabel = UILabel()
            currentView.addSubview(leftLabel)
        }

        // Mapping from width to a scale of 1 to 25
        let minScale: CGFloat = 1
        let maxScale: CGFloat = 25

        // Calculate the scale for width
        let widthScale = minScale + (newWidth / view.bounds.width) * (maxScale - minScale)

        // Update label text for width
        bottomLabel.text = "\(Int(widthScale))"  // Bottom label measures width
        leftLabel.text = "\(Int(currentHeight))"   // Left label always shows the fixed height

        bottomLabel.textAlignment = .center
        leftLabel.textAlignment = .center

        // Set label sizes (ensure they have a minimum width and height)
        let labelWidth: CGFloat = 50
        let labelHeight: CGFloat = 20

        // Reposition the bottom label to be at the bottom center, measuring width
        bottomLabel.frame = CGRect(
            x: (newWidth - labelWidth) / 2,  // Center horizontally
            y: currentHeight - labelHeight,    // Align at the bottom
            width: labelWidth,
            height: labelHeight
        )

        // Reposition the left label to be at the left center, measuring height
        leftLabel.frame = CGRect(
            x: 0,  // Align to the left edge
            y: ( currentHeight - labelHeight) / 2,  // Center vertically
            width: labelWidth,
            height: labelHeight
        )
    }

    @objc func handleTapGestured(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        currentView = gesture.view
        // Set slider value to match the size of the selected box
      
    }
    
    @objc func handlePanGestured(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let draggedView = gesture.view!
        view.bringSubviewToFront(draggedView)
        
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        draggedView.center = CGPoint(x: draggedView.center.x + translation.x, y: draggedView.center.y + translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
        
        currentView = gesture.view
    }
    func createToolbar() -> UIToolbar {
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonTapped))

    toolbar.items = [flexSpace, doneButton]
    return toolbar
    }

    @objc func doneButtonTapped() {
    view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    func saver() {
        let vex = self.view.screenshot(for: view.frame, clipToBounds: true, with: UIImage(named: "")).pngData()
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Item", in: managedContext)!
        let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Item")
        
        
        if let data = vex{
            item.setValue(data, forKey: "image")
            print(data)
        }
        
        if txt.text == ""{
            item.setValue("", forKey: "atBATS")
        }
        if txt.text != ""{
            item.setValue(txt.text, forKey: "atBATS")
        }
        
        
        
        
        do {
            let result = try? managedContext.fetch(fetch) as? [Item]
            print("Queen",result?.count)
            try? managedContext.save()
            
            
            
        }
        catch {
            print("Could not save")
        }
        
        
    }
    
    @objc func libraryBtn() {
        let vc = twoViewController()
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // actually .fullScreen would be better
        self.present(vc, animated: true)
  
    }

}
extension UIView {
    /// Takes a screenshot of a UIView, with an option to clip to view bounds and place a waterwark image
    /// - Parameter rect: offset and size of the screenshot to take
    /// - Parameter clipToBounds: Bool to check where self.bounds and rect intersect and adjust size so there is no empty space
    /// - Parameter watermark: UIImage of the watermark to place on top
    func screenshot(for rect: CGRect, clipToBounds: Bool = true, with watermark: UIImage? = nil) -> UIImage {
        var imageRect = rect
        if clipToBounds {
            imageRect = bounds.intersection(rect)
        }
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: imageRect).image { _ in
            drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: bounds.size), afterScreenUpdates: true)
            watermark?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
        }
    }
}




class twoViewController: UIViewController {
    var itemName : [Item] = []
    
    fileprivate let collectionView:UICollectionView = {
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cv.isScrollEnabled = true
        
        return cv
    }()
    
    var backButton = UIButton()
    @objc func moveLeft() {
        
        
        
        
        
        let vcx = ViewController()
        vcx.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // actually .fullScreen would be better
        self.present(vcx, animated: true)}
    
    
    
    
    
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
        do {
            self.itemName = try managedContext.fetch(fetch)
        }
        catch {
            print("Could not load. \(error)")
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //        setupCollection()
        loadData()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemPurple
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        backButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        backButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray
        backButton.setTitle("back", for: .normal)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        //
        collectionView.reloadData()
        
        
        
        view.addSubview(backButton)
        
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveLeft), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.9, constant: 0),
            collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier:  1, constant: 0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),
            
            
            backButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor),
            backButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.1, constant: 0),
            backButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier:  1, constant: 0),
            backButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),
            
            
            
        ])
        
    }
    
    
    
}
extension twoViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/1.5, height: collectionView.frame.width/2)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemName.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        
        let title = itemName[indexPath.row]
        let attr1 = title.value(forKey: "atBATS") as? String
        
        let text = ["  ", attr1].compactMap { $0 }.reduce("", +)
        
        if let imageData = itemName[indexPath.row].image {
            
            let coredataLoadedimage = UIImage(data: imageData)
            cell.ii.image = coredataLoadedimage
            //
        }
        cell.parentVC = self
        
        cell.tt.text = text
        
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
        
        cell.bt2.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.bt2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(elete), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    @objc func elete(_ sender:UIButton){
        
        
        
        
        let note = itemName[sender.tag]
        
        
        let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        managedContext.delete(note)
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            collectionView.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        
        
        
    }
}





class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    
    
    var parentVC: UIViewController!
    
    var  bg: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        return iv
    }()
    
    var  bt: UIButton = {
        let bt = UIButton()
        bt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bt.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        bt.clipsToBounds = true
        bt.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        return bt
    }()
    
    
    var  bt2: UIButton = {
        let bt2 = UIButton()
        bt2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bt2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        bt2.clipsToBounds = true
        bt2.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        return bt2
    }()
    
    
    var  tt: UILabel = {
        let tt = UILabel()
        tt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tt.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        tt.clipsToBounds = true
        
        return tt
    }()
    
    var  ii: UIImageView = {
        let ii = UIImageView()
        ii.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        ii.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        ii.clipsToBounds = true
        
        return ii
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        [bt2,bt,bg,ii,tt].forEach({
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.contentView.addSubview($0)
        })
        
        bt.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemPink
        bt2.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        bt.setTitle("show", for: .normal)
        bt2.setTitle("delete", for: .normal)
        
        ii.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray
        tt.textAlignment = .center
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
            
            bg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor, constant :20),
            bg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor, constant : 0),
            bg.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            bg.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            
            
            ii.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor, constant :40),
            ii.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor, constant : -40),
            ii.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            ii.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            
            
            tt.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor, constant :45),
            tt.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor, constant : -80),
            tt.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90),
            tt.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            
            
            bt.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor, constant :0),
            bt.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor, constant : 45),
            bt.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            bt.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            
            
            bt2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor, constant :60),
            bt2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor, constant : 45),
            bt2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            bt2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            
            
        ])
        
        bt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveRight), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    @objc func moveRight() {
        
        
        let vce = fullScreen()
        vce.text = tt.text!
        vce.newImage = ii.image!
        
        
        
        vce.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // actually .fullScreen would be better
        parentVC.present(vce, animated: true)}
    
    
    
    
    
}

class fullScreen : UIViewController{
    var i = UIImageView()
    var l = UILabel()
    var back = UIButton()
    var newImage: UIImage!
    var text:String = ""
    var counter = 0
    var oldCons = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    var nw = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        l.text = text
        i.image = newImage
        back.setTitle("back", for: .normal)
        l.textAlignment = .center
        view.addSubview(i)
        i.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(l)
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        back.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(back)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
        l.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray
        i.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        back.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        
        
        i.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        oldCons = [
            i.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :150),  i.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :150),
            i.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : -200),
            
            i.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            i.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450),
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(oldCons)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
            
            
            
            
            
            back.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            back.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            
            back.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 1.0),
            back.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            
            
            l.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :75),
            l.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : -260),
            
            l.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
            l.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            
            
        ])
        
        
        
        let tg = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.selena))
        i.addGestureRecognizer(tg)
        back.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveRight), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        
    }
    
    
    @objc func selena(){
        if counter % 2 == 0 {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(oldCons)
            
            nw = [
                i.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
                i.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
                i.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
                i.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
            ]
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(nw)
            l.isHidden = true
            back.isHidden = true
            
            print("hello")
        }else{
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(nw)
            
            nw = [
                i.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :150),  i.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :150),
                i.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : -200),
                i.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
                i.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450),
                
            ]
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(nw)
            
            l.isHidden = false
            back.isHidden = false
            print("dissy")
            
        }
        counter += 1
    }
    
    @objc func moveRight() {
        
        let vc = twoViewController()
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // actually .fullScreen would be better
        self.present(vc, animated: true)
        
        
    }
    var inital : Item?
    
    @objc func backF() {
        // Take a screenshot of the draw view
        guard let imageData = self.view.screenshot(for: view.frame, clipToBounds: true).pngData() else {
            // Handle the case where screenshot or PNG data is nil
            return
        }

        // Ensure there is an 'Inital' object
        guard let budget = inital else {
            return
        }


        // Save the changes to Core Data
        DataManger.shared.saveContext()

        // Dismiss the current view controller
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    
    
}

